# Circular Progress Bar not stopping at desired percentage

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

I am creating a circular progress bar for my project.

[Desired Progress Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCCeQ.png)

I have done following in html css and jquery but the issue is i am not getting how to stop it at a desired percentage. It always completes to 100%. i want to stop it on a specific point.

HTML/CSS JS

```js
function setProgress(elem, percent) {
    var
      degrees = percent * 3.6,
      transform = /MSIE 9/.test(navigator.userAgent) ? 'msTransform' : 'transform';
    elem.querySelector('.counter').setAttribute('data-percent', Math.round(percent));
    elem.querySelector('.progressEnd').style[transform] = 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)';
    elem.querySelector('.progress').style[transform] = 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)';
    if (percent >= 50 && !/(^|\s)fiftyPlus(\s|$)/.test(elem.className))
        elem.className += ' fiftyPlus';
}

(function () {
    var
      elem = document.querySelector('.circlePercent'),
      percent = 0;
    (function animate() {
        setProgress(elem, (percent += .25));
        if (percent < 100)
            setTimeout(animate, 15);
    })();
})();
```

```css
.circlePercent {
  position: relative;
  top: 26px;
  left: 26px;
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: orange;
}
.circlePercent:before,
.circlePercent > .progressEnd {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 2px;
  left: 45px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  -ms-transform-origin: 3px 46px;
  transform-origin: 3px 46px;
  content: "";
}
.circlePercent:after,
.circlePercent > .progress {
  position: absolute;
  -ms-transform-origin: 48px 48px;
  transform-origin: 48px 48px;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 48px;
  height: 96px;
  border-radius: 48px 0 0 48px;
  background: orange;
  content: "";
}
.circlePercent.fiftyPlus:after {
  background: white;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.circlePercent > .progress.progress {
  background: white;
}
.circlePercent > .counter {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-left: -2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid orange;
}
.circlePercent > .counter:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -13px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 26px;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  content: attr(data-percent) "%";
}
.circlePercent > .counter:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: orange;
  content: "";
}
.circlePercent > .counter[data-percent="100"] {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="circlePercent">
            <div class="counter" data-percent="0"></div>
            <div class="progress"></div>
            <div class="progressEnd"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="scripts/radialloader.js"></script>
```

Kindly help me out of it.

Comment: can you please create a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p4gttdua/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your code and now I have set the variable `stopPercent` to `50`. So loading will be stopped at `50%`. Is this what you need?

```js
function setProgress(elem, percent) {
    var
      degrees = percent * 3.6,
      transform = /MSIE 9/.test(navigator.userAgent) ? 'msTransform' : 'transform';
    elem.querySelector('.counter').setAttribute('data-percent', Math.round(percent));
    elem.querySelector('.progressEnd').style[transform] = 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)';
    elem.querySelector('.progress').style[transform] = 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)';
    if (percent >= 50 && !/(^|\s)fiftyPlus(\s|$)/.test(elem.className))
        elem.className += ' fiftyPlus';
}

   (function () {
var elem = document.querySelector('.circlePercent'),percent = 0,stopped = false,stopPercent = 50;
(function animate() {
    setProgress(elem, (percent += .25));
    if (percent < 100 && !stopped)
        setTimeout(animate, 15);
  if(percent == stopPercent){
   stopped = true;
  }
})();
})();
```

```css
.circlePercent {
  position: relative;
  top: 26px;
  left: 26px;
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: orange;
}
.circlePercent:before,
.circlePercent > .progressEnd {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 2px;
  left: 45px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  -ms-transform-origin: 3px 46px;
  transform-origin: 3px 46px;
  content: "";
}
.circlePercent:after,
.circlePercent > .progress {
  position: absolute;
  -ms-transform-origin: 48px 48px;
  transform-origin: 48px 48px;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 48px;
  height: 96px;
  border-radius: 48px 0 0 48px;
  background: orange;
  content: "";
}
.circlePercent.fiftyPlus:after {
  background: white;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.circlePercent > .progress.progress {
  background: white;
}
.circlePercent > .counter {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-left: -2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid orange;
}
.circlePercent > .counter:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -13px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 26px;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  content: attr(data-percent) "%";
}
.circlePercent > .counter:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: orange;
  content: "";
}
.circlePercent > .counter[data-percent="100"] {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="circlePercent">
            <div class="counter" data-percent="0"></div>
            <div class="progress"></div>
            <div class="progressEnd"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="scripts/radialloader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks alot :). Thumbs Up (Y)